# Flink CEP all previous events cleared from the state on a match

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a particular case in flink CEP where all the events are discarded on a single match. For example let us take an example input of Apple, And, All, Bulb, Bee, Bell. The condition is word starting with A followed by word starting with B. But the match returns only the first match and it is skipping the remaining matches so only Apple Bulb is returned, others are discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You should experiment with the various options for [AfterMatchSkipStrategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html#after-match-skip-strategy) and the different ways of [combining patterns](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/cep.html#combining-patterns). For example, if you use `AfterMatchSkipStrategy.noSkip()` in combination with `followedByAny()`, then all 9 matches are returned.

```java
DataStream<String> stringInputStream = environment.fromElements(
    "apple", "and", "all", "bulb", "bee", "bell");

AfterMatchSkipStrategy skipStrategy = AfterMatchSkipStrategy.noSkip();
Pattern<String, ?> pattern = Pattern.<String>begin("start", skipStrategy)
        .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean filter(String s) throws Exception {
                return (s.charAt(0) == 'a');
            }
        }).followedByAny("next")
        .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean filter(String s) throws Exception {
                return (s.charAt(0) == 'b');
            }
        });

PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(stringInputStream, pattern);
DataStream<String> result = patternStream.process(
        new PatternProcessFunction<String, String>() {

    @Override
    public void processMatch(
            Map<String, List<String>> map,
            Context context,
            Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect(map.toString());
    }
});
result.print();
```

```
{start=[apple], next=[bulb]}
{start=[and], next=[bulb]}
{start=[all], next=[bulb]}
{start=[apple], next=[bee]}
{start=[and], next=[bee]}
{start=[all], next=[bee]}
{start=[apple], next=[bell]}
{start=[and], next=[bell]}
{start=[all], next=[bell]}
```

However, you need to be careful. Setting up patterns that require storing events indefinitely will lead to poor performance and ultimately to job failures. You want to constrain the matches as much as possible.

Comment: Hi my requirement is to match them uniquely like first we match apple , bulb. Next the remaining elements are all, and, bee, bell, So we match all and  bee. Finally we match the remaining and, bell. Is this possible using CEP.

Comment: I've retracted my update -- it didn't correctly address your requirements. For this use case, I would use a ProcessFunction rather than CEP.

Comment: Is there any possibility to combine cep along with this since I would require complex patterns offered by cep for my use case